# Delete section based on search condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My requirenament is to delete a Relation tag where `@guid` match with one of Relation's `@relationObj` where `<roleCode tc=32>` or `<roleCode tc=31>` or `<roleCode tc=8>` only.
The above logic is also applicable to `@relationObj` that should match with  one of Relation's `@relationObj` where `<roleCode tc=32>` or `<roleCode tc=31>` or `<roleCode tc=8>` only.

Basically i want to search `@guid` and `@relationObj` by looking up other Relation tags where `@relationObj` belongs to `<roleCode tc=32>` or `<roleCode tc=31>` or `<roleCode tc=8>`. If this condition is true delete this section.

Below is the XML :

```
<Relations>
<Relation guid="abcd1234" relationObj="1234">
    <roleCode tc="20"/>
</Relation>
<Relation guid="xyz123" relationObj="1111">
    <roleCode tc="32"/>
</Relation>

<Relation guid="def123" relationObj="2222">
    <roleCode tc="31"/>
</Relation>

<Relation guid="1111" relationObj="2222">
    <roleCode tc="98"/>
</Relation>

<Relation guid="jkl123" relationObj="3333">
    <roleCode tc="8"/>
</Relation>

<Relation guid="2222" relationObj="1234">
    <roleCode tc="100"/>
</Relation>
</Relations>
```

I tried creating three variables to extract `@relationObj` for each `<roleCode tc>[32,31 and 8]` inside the template. And then comparing `@objectId` and `@relationObj` with these three variables. But the problem here is , the variable is getting updated to empty value when it encounters another `<Relation>` tag while iterating.

From above xml i should get below xml after transformation.

```
<Relations>
<Relation guid="abcd1234" relationObj="1234">
    <roleCode tc="20"/>
</Relation>
<Relation guid="xyz123" relationObj="1111">
    <roleCode tc="32"/>
</Relation>

<Relation guid="def123" relationObj="2222">
    <roleCode tc="31"/>
</Relation>
<Relation guid="jkl123" relationObj="3333">
    <roleCode tc="8"/>
</Relation>
<Relation guid="2222" relationObj="1234">
    <roleCode tc="100"/>
</Relation>
</Relations>
```

If you observe, the `<Relation>` tag with [guid="1111" relationObj="2222"] is deleted. Because both @guid and @relationObj belongs to one of the roleCodes - 32,31 or 8.

Could you please let me know what is the best to save the value in a variable without updating with new one? or is there any better approach i can achieve this. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by defining a *key* that will let you extract all the `roleCode` values for a particular `relationObj`, and then use that key to pick the `Relation` elements to exclude.  If I understand your requirements correctly then I think this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="roleCodeByRelObj" match="roleCode" use="../@relationObj" />

  <!-- copy input to output except where more specific template applies -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore any Relation whose guid and relationObj match the relationObj of a
       Relation whose roleCode/@tc is 8, 31 or 32 (not necessarily the same
       matching Relation in both cases) -->
  <xsl:template match="Relation[
       (
         (key('roleCodeByRelObj', @guid)/@tc = '8') or
         (key('roleCodeByRelObj', @guid)/@tc = '31') or
         (key('roleCodeByRelObj', @guid)/@tc = '32')
       )
     and
       (
         (key('roleCodeByRelObj', @relationObj)/@tc = '8') or
         (key('roleCodeByRelObj', @relationObj)/@tc = '31') or
         (key('roleCodeByRelObj', @relationObj)/@tc = '32')
       )
    ]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The way equality tests work in XPath when one side is a node set is that the test is true if *any* of the nodes in the set match the value.  Thus for

```
key('roleCodeByRelObj', @guid)/@tc = '31'
```

when `guid` is "2222" you get two `roleCode` elements back from the key function (`tc=31` and `tc=98`), and the overall test succeeds because one of them matches the target value.

Comment: Thank your for your update. Applying above xslt , the last relation tag [ guid="2222" relationObj="1234"] should not be deleted. Because @relationObj="1234" belongs to roleCode 20 which is not in the condition. Please see my updated output xml.

Comment: @MadhuCM in your original question you said that the 2222/1234 relation _should_ be deleted.  Are you now changing the requirements so you only want to delete relations where _both_ the `guid` _and_ the `relationObj` match a (possibly different) `Relation/@relationObj` whose `roleCode` is one of the three?

Comment: the last relation's @guid="2222" belongs to roleCode 31 but @relationObj="1234" does not belong to any of roleCodes (32,31, or 8). So it basically should work with AND condition to delete the relation section.

Comment: you are true i am checking for both the guid and the relationObj match a (possibly different) Relation/@relationObj whose roleCode is one of the three.

Comment: @MadhuCM OK, how about this version?